# Trouble changing the color of an input placeholder

Tags: html, css, placeholder

I am trying to figure out how to change to color of the placeholder's in the text boxes in my form.  I've found a few tutorials online ([like this one](http://htmlcolorcodes.com/tutorials/css-placeholder-color/)) that show how, but I'm not getting it to to work.

```
<form action="/Home/Register" id="RegisterForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm required" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name*" type="text" value="" aria-required="true">
</form>
```

Then, in the CSS, I have tried these:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#434c53}
::-moz-placeholder{color:#434c53}
:-ms-input-placeholder{color:#434c53}
input.form-control ::placeholder{color:#434c53}
```

And also:

```
input.form-control ::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#434c53}
input.form-control ::-moz-placeholder{color:#434c53}
input.form-control :-ms-input-placeholder{color:#434c53}
input.form-control ::placeholder{color:#434c53}
```

And also:

```
.form-control ::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#434c53}
.form-control ::-moz-placeholder{color:#434c53}
.form-control :-ms-input-placeholder{color:#434c53}
.form-control ::placeholder{color:#434c53}
```

And some other combinations. Nothing I try is working.

Comment: The last two blocks look like they would work if you remove the whitespace between class identifier and the `::` since you're not looking for descendents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder='global'>

<input class='red' type="text" placeholder='red'>
```

-

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: blue;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: blue;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  color: blue;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  color: blue;
}

.red::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/m9rtjgea/)